# Jquery not work when include to master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using [this slide show](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideshowJmpress/) ,  I included all the script and css to my master page of ASP.net MVC project. But the all the element of the slide didn't show in my page. Only the next and previous button are working, the image and text didn't. In my master page I have only the script of the slide so it has no the conflict script or jquery problem.

I view the page source and click to each link of external css and script, it work properly.

But I really have no idea what happen to my page.

This is the code that I include and HTML

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Web.Models" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
Home Page    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/homegallery/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/homegallery/css/demo.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/homegallery/js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/homegallery/js/jmpress.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/homegallery/js/jquery.jmslideshow.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/homegallery/js/modernizr.custom.48780.js"></script>

  <noscript>
   <style>
      .step {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
      }
      .step:not(.active) {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=99);
       -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)";
       }
     .step:not(.active) a.jms-link{
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 40px;
     }
 </style>
 </noscript>
    <div id="home" style="width: 890px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top:28px; margin-bottom: -50px;">
    <div class="container">
        <section id="jms-slideshow" class="jms-slideshow">
            <div class="step" data-color="color-1">
                <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3>Just when I thought...</h3>
                    <p>From fairest creatures we desire increase, that thereby beauty's rose might never die</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <img src="../../Product/2309.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="step" data-color="color-1" data-y="500" data-scale="0.4" data-rotate-x="30">
                <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3>Holy cannoli!</h3>
                    <p>But as the riper should by time decease, his tender heir might bear his memory</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
                <img src="../../Product/2070.jpg" />
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#jms-slideshow').jmslideshow();
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Any one have any idea please.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Can you post the plugin configuration code with the HTML mark up required for that image sections?

Comment: @Murali : I added ready Murali, Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I tried. It is working for me. Please run in FireFox with firebug addon for request/script debugging. Also check the view source and click on CSS file links and Scripts file links to make sure it shows the content. Check the image src attribute file link too

Comment: Yes sure, I checked it already, all the link shows the content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following:

1. Order of including scripts.
2. Save html page from browser, and compare code with examples on site. Line by line.
3. Check varibale which contains img urls and text, may you have spelling mistake

Comment: when I used the firebug to check, all the images are correct. and the script also included. And the HTML that I scrap from the browser work.

Comment: may you have some route rules, that does not give possibility to load img twice. OR you have other js code that executed after document.ready and after creation slider

Comment: In the the master page, I only have this slider script, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. Please check the order and url to the css, images, scripts

```
<link href="Scripts/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jmpress.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jmslideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.48780.js"></script>
<noscript>
        <style>
            .step
            {
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }
            .step:not(.active)
            {
                opacity: 1;
                filter: alpha(opacity=99);
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)";
            }
            .step:not(.active) a.jms-link
            {
                opacity: 1;
                margin-top: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>


<div id="home" style="width: 890px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 28px; margin-bottom: -50px;">
            <div class="container">
                <section id="jms-slideshow" class="jms-slideshow">
                    <div class="step" data-color="color-1">
                        <div class="jms-content">
                            <h3>
                                Just when I thought...</h3>
                            <p>
                                From fairest creatures we desire increase, that thereby beauty's rose might never
                                die</p>
                            <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                        <img src="Images/4.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="step" data-color="color-1" data-y="500" data-scale="0.4" data-rotate-x="30">
                        <div class="jms-content">
                            <h3>
                                Holy cannoli!</h3>
                            <p>
                                But as the riper should by time decease, his tender heir might bear his memory</p>
                            <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                        <img src="Images/5.png" />
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#jms-slideshow').jmslideshow();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: It still not working Murali. Is it because of my master page? Because when I do it beside my project, it works.